# Does there exist a way to simplify or build a table to find the truth in a set of given statements involving 5 individuals?

Tags: logic, puzzle, word-problem

This problem has got me going in circles for several hours and I'm not sure what to do, the problem is as follows:

> At a semiconductor laboratory in Hsinchu a security guard caught five
>   technicians accessing a high level security area reserved for the most
>   trusted scientists working in a new integrated circuit for an upcoming
>   computer. However the security film is not very clear and the security
>   team can only be sure that four out of five technicians have the
>   access key card to enter the chipset room.
>
> During interrogation the security team deduces that two of the
>   technicians are lying and the other are telling the truth.
>
> The answers given by the laboratory technicians were as follows:
>
> Audrey: Gwendolyn does not have an access credential.
>
> Dorothy: I was entrusted an access key.
>
> Marina: Hannah has an access key.
>
> Gwendolyn: Audrey is lying.
>
> Hannah: Dorothy is telling the truth.
>
> Based on this information. Which of the technicians does not have
>   access to the chipset room?

Typically I would provide something but in this case I'm stuck at the very beginning. So far the only thing that I found it is that such problem seems to be a [Knights and knaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_and_Knaves) kind which is related to logic. But in this case there are five individuals, hence the number of possible combinations would mean $2^5=32$ which raises a flag to me as $32$ combinations seems too big to make it a practical approach to try one by one. Therefore I need help into finding a solution or a method which would ease and simplify or solve this problem easily.

Can somebody help me with this? I'm not very knowledgeable with this type of problems. It would help me a lot to visualize what's going on if the proposed solution would include some sort of table or grid so I could identify the concluded result.

Comment: It seems like some rules have been left out.  If, say, I guess that $A$ is the one who had no access then I see that the truth values are $(F,T,T,T,T)$.  If I guess that $G$ is the one without access then they are $(T,T,T,F,T)$.  Why should I prefer one of those to the other?

Comment: To your question:  there are only $5$ possible truth tables here (unless I misunderstand).  We know that exactly one of these people lacks access, so there is one truth table for each of the five.

Comment: A condition of the form “at least or at most these many people lied” has to be there in the question. Please don’t go in circles if the question is incompletely stated

Comment: @lulu I'm so sorry. There was a missing information in the problem. I'm doing an edit to include that part so maybe that can help solving the problem. For the other part you mentioned that there are only $5$ possible truth tables. But I meant that there are $32$ possible $T$ and $F$ combinations. That's what I meant. Or could I be mistaken?. Sorry. I'm new on this.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell  But you have external information which lets you narrow down the number of tables.  If I flip a fair coin and $A$ says "It's $H$" and $B$ says "It's $T$" Then the only truth tables are $(T,F),(F,T)$.

Comment: Just seen the edit, and now you do not need to go in circles any more : start by assuming that Someone, say Aubrey does not have the access key. Find out who is lying, and who is telling the truth. You know that exactly two liars are there. If Aubrey does not work out, do the same thing with say Dorothy , and so on. I was always suspicious about Hannah even before the edit!

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell  Can you solve the problem now?  My first comment, for instance, clears Audrey and Gwendolyn.  All you have to do is to test the other three.

Comment: @lulu The problem is **I don't know what am I suppose to do first** the thing about *true* or *false* tables was just some of my initial findings in other sources which indicated what may be required to solve these kind of situation. Namely assigning a knight and knave (whether not sure if applies here) a true and false value, and then going from there. But in this case what to do?. Therefore a more proper solution involving building a table or something visual would be better suited for assesing my understanding.How am I suppose to know what to narrow if I can't get to know what to do first?

Comment: You are over thinking this. I showed you what to do in my first comment.  Assume in turn that each one lacked access and see how the truth values play out.  I'll post something below, but you should really try to do it on your own before looking.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I still cannot solve this problem by my own as mentally I don't know what should I start out. Maybe would you want to try writting an answer. Doing my own effort into this so far is Hannah who might be the one without access key, assuming Marina and Gwendolyn are lying. Could I be right on this assumption?

Comment: @lulu Again, i'm sorry if it sounds too imperative but it takes time to catch up and do mental effort into this. As in my comment from earlier. By going into deduction I could come that the quickest "possible" answer would be Hannah without the credential assuming that two girls are lying namely Marina and Gwendolyn. But this arises the fact, would another combination be possible or more over, is my assumption correct?

Comment: Perfect. You are doing things correctly. See, as I mentioned earlier, you just need to pick a girl, assume that she is the wrong un, and then check who is lying and who is not. You have done that, by checking that everything matches up with Hannah. To know that no one else can be the wrong one, you simply have to start with someone other than Hannah and then see that either more or less than two people were lying in that case. This is what lulu has done below , which is show that exactly two people are lying exactly when Hannah  is the wrong one

Comment: I'd say you should check all five cases regardless.  You could, of course, trust that the authors of the problem made sure that there was only one solution that satisfied all the constraints, but it's so easy to check all $5$ that I'd just do that even if you have hit upon one possible solution.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks!. I think your comment did helped a bit into guiding me what to do in similar situations (although I would appreciate that someone could venture into being more verboise into this). Maybe is off-topic but my computer doesn't really display cyrilic alphabet correctly. Is your avatar/pseudonym Aston Villa?. I just want to be polite and not incur into any mistake. Anyways, thanks!.

Comment: You are welcome! I am a fan of Aston Villa for the past nine years ,essentially from a young age. I love Cyrillic script too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new information (that exactly $2$ are lying) we can solve the problem.

There are $5$ states to consider according to whichever lacked access.  We list them all:

If $A$ lacked access:  $(F,T,T,T,T)$

If $D$ lacked access:  $(F,F,T,T,F)$

If $M$ lacked access:  $(F,T,T,T,T)$

If $G$ lacked access  $(T,T,T,F,T)$

If $H$ lacked access:  $(F,T,F, T,T)$

By inspection, Hannah is the guilty party.

To stress:  we need some rule to let us know how to evaluate the various True-False configurations.  A priori, we have no idea what they might mean.  A natural rule would be, say, "the person who lacked access is lying, everyone else is telling the truth".  That rule doesn't lead to a unique solution here (though you can narrow down the list of suspects to $A,G$.  As it stands, we are given the rule "exactly two people are lying".  Happily, that rule does lead to a unique solution.

Comment: For some reason I suspected that Gwendolyn could be the one telling lies. But this was more of intuition or just assigning a psicological method of defense, neither any logical aspect on it. For the rest looking at the tables. I'm still confused. What does the order of trues and falses mean. Each statement?. But from looking at this I can understand the source of your initial confusion. For starters, do I get the impression that there can only be one $F$ value for each row?. If so meant that what to choose $G$ or $A$? as each one satisfies that condition.

Comment: $D$ is the row with more $F$ and it doesn't seem to be logical way as there are only two possible $\textrm{F's}$ not three, so the remaning $H$ should be the answer. Again, with no prior experience in these kinds of problems that would be my assumption based on your answer. Still with few words I believe that a more graphical approach or a step-by-step solution would assess better what I requested rather a straightforward answer, which isn't bad as it solves the problem but doesn't aid much to the OP (me) to understand what to think and what to look first.

Comment: Just go statement by statement.  Don't focus on who is lying, at least at first.  Focus on who lacked access.  Let's say $A$ lacked access.  Then $A$ is lying (since $G$ did have access), $D$ is telling the truth, $M$ is telling the truth, $G$ is telling the truth, and $H$ is telling the truth.  We now just list those values as $(F,T,T,T,T)$.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment at all.  The rules say that exactly two of the given statements are false.  Under the assumption that $D$ lacks access , three of the statements are false so our assumption must be incorrect. Hence we deduce that $D$ really did have access.

Comment: As to a step by step solution, I honestly don't see how anything could be more step-by-step than what I wrote.  There are $5$ states of the world, according to which one lacked access.  I simply look at each of those $5$ states one at a time.  No shortcuts are taken.  As it happens, the guilty party was revealed on the fifth try, but I'd have listed all $5$ regardless...just for completeness.   If there were $500$ states I'd look for a shortcut.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explained myself better in the second comment. What I meant was that without the added clue (before editing the question), the logical answer would be the one where only one $F$ value per row satisfy or be the answer. But since there are two girls whose statements are valid, which one to choose. Then, after I added the missing close it reduced to the fifth girl which would satisfy that condition rulling out all the other possibilities. That's what I intended to say. For the rest of rows the more $\textrm{F's}$ are just assigning that what it was said is a lie.

Comment: Since there can only exits two $F$ and not just one $F$ neither three $F$ then the right answer would be the girl with two $F$ referring to the row you wrote, which I believe you're saying table.

Comment: I don't understand.  A priori we have no reason to assume that anybody is lying or that anybody is telling the truth.  Maybe all five are lying, maybe all five are telling the truth.  Who knows?  We need some rule to go by.  Here the rule is "exactly two people are lying."  Fine.  We can work with that.  But we need some sort of rule.  Once I have the rule, then I just look to see which state of the world satisfies that rule.  Here, only the state "Hannah lacked access" satisfies the rule.

Comment: You could try different rules, but I doubt that a randomly chosen rule would lead to a unique solution.  If, say, you said "the person who lacked access is lying, everyone else is telling the truth" then the best we can say is that it's one of $A,G$ who lacked access.

Comment: For what I meant as step by step solution was actually a bit of what you wrote in the comments. As to say "To solve this problem, begin by building a 5x2 table, one which has the names of the individuals and the other with a bracket with a summary of the assumptions, assign T or F as needed". Of course this is brief, but stated in that way would had been much better for me to understand. I know you cannot see in my mind what is exactly what I don't understand. But stated in this way for me would had been more clearer.

Comment: Hopefully in this particular problem just inspection by going to a fifth try solved it. Again, sorry if this sounds too convoluted or asking for nitpicky details but individuals at my age tend to have slow (very slow) learning speeds. But thanks, i'll take your suggestions in similar problems from now on.

Comment: I voice my support that your comment of "A priori and from then on" to be upgraded and be added to your answer. This adds much value to it since I find it helpful. To solve this riddle, just requires patience to assign $T$ or $F$ to each statement given that what it is being put to test is a pivot. i.e If statement 1 is true, then statement 2 much check otherwise will be false and so on. Am I understanding this correctly?. For this I belive your comment should be added to your answer. Again, thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

If G is telling the truth then A is lying and vice versa. So exactly one of A or G is a liar.

Since there are exactly two liars then exactly one of D, M and H is the second liar.

D and H are either both telling the truth or both lying. But if they are both liars then there are three liars altogether. So they are both telling the truth.

Therefore the second liar is M, so Hannah does not have an access key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write five tables and then see if the person is lying or not based in this table, the exercise ask for a table that has two people lying, is this case would be the table $(H, H, H, H, N)$ h stands for has the key and n for does not have the key. So the last person does not have the credential to access this laboratory.